# Calling global method from a local function typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I'm fairly new to typescript coding but I've been managing fine so far with prior knowledge of coding, but I've stumbled a problem that I wasn't able to find a comprehensible answer... I think.

```
myMethod1(){
  function mySubMethod(){
  //Call myMethod2 here.
  }
}
myMethod2(){
//do something
}
```

Is this possible?
Sorry about this and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely possible, because `mySubMethod` is declared in a scope nested *inside* the scope that `myMethod2` is declared in. Inner scopes can access outer scope bindings, just not the other way around.

You do need to declare the functions correctly, though:

```js
function myMethod1(){
    function mySubMethod(){
        myMethod2();
    }
    mySubMethod();
}
function myMethod2(){
    console.log("myMethod2 ran");
}
myMethod1();
```

---

Side note: As shown, what you have there are *functions*, not *methods*. Methods are associated with an object.

---

In a comment you've clarified:

> myMethod1 and myMethod2 are methods and mySubMethod is a function and not a method

So that sounds like this:

```js
class Example {
    myMethod1(){
        function mySubMethod(){
            this.myMethod2();
        }
        mySubMethod.call(this);
        
        // Easier with an arrow function:
        const mySubFunction = () => {
            this.myMethod2();
        };
        mySubFunction();
    }
    myMethod2(){
        console.log("myMethod2 ran");
    }
}
const e = new Example();
e.myMethod1();
```

Mostly it's about managing `this` in this particular case. More:

- [*How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)
- [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)